# In the Powershell how can I extract 1000 characters before and after a found pattern

Tags: windows, powershell, grep

I have a large file (3mb)  and I need to extract 1000 characters before and after a found pattern.

I am currently using 
    `Select-String -Pattern "695614"` in the Power Shell but this is printing out the entire file, there are not line breaks in this file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should handle that;

```
(get-content c:\somedir\somefile.txt -raw) -replace '.*(.{1000}695614.{1000}).*','$1'
```